# Determine if touch event up is part of zoom or not?

Tags: java, android, andengine, pinchzoom

In my game, the player can pinch to zoom the camera in and out. The player also taps the screen to move, which is triggered by the finger being lifted from the screen. After zooming the camera with a pinch, the move event is also triggered, which I want to stop from happening, but am not sure of a way to do this. This is the segment of my onSceneTouchEvent that controls this:

```
if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
        playerMove = true; //move the player, which is done somewhere else
        moveX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
        moveY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
    }
    pinchZoomDetector.onTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);
```

Comment: It seems like all MotionEvents are terminated by the Up action. I wonder if there'll be a correct answer here or if it's better to make your game controls work in a slightly different way.

Comment: I have gotten close before, but have had that same problem. Pinch to zoom isn't critical to the game, it's just the most intuitive way to do it, and moving the character after its done is just an annoyance. I might end of changing how its done.